# How to edit Configuration and write to the .xml file in HDFS?

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, configuration, hdfs

I know that Hadoop has a set of API to use Configuration.

Here is the question. I need edit the properties in the .xml at run time.

For example, there is a configuration file named "hdfs-a.xml", i load it in my java code.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource("/hdfs-a.xml");
conf.set("dfs.test.num", 2);
```

how can i change the value of "dfs.test.num" in file "hdfs-a.xml"  to "2"?

**Is there any way to edit the .xml file in java code at run time?**

Comment: Try and see what happen. And please share your findings.

Comment: You will surely find a way to edit the file in SO itself, but I think the changes won't get reflected until demons(ie -cluster) get restarted.

Comment: I tried, and i think maybe the only way to change the "*.xml" file is to write to the file using filesystem interface. There is no method offered by hadoop to persistent the changes to .xml file automaticly.